# how to escape xml space in service?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

hi now i m working with XSLT and now i call to a service

as like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="ext">
                    <config type="2" liveserver="XXX.com" localserver="XXX.com" httpuri="/myservices/jsonrequesthomenew?companyid=homepage&amp;outputtype=xml" params="" readtimeout="10000"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

if  i cehck to this  live url than show to this result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<indexes>
    <data>
        <sensex>
            <CloseIndexValue>25719.58</CloseIndexValue>
            <trend>equal</trend>
            <premarket>false</premarket>
            <DateTime>03:53 PM | 10 Sep 2015</DateTime>
            <CurrentIndexValue>25622.17</CurrentIndexValue>
            <Segment>BSE</Segment>
            <OpenIndexValue>25522.96</OpenIndexValue>
            <IndexName>SENSEX</IndexName>
            <PercentChange>-0.38</PercentChange>
            <NetChange>-97.41</NetChange>
        </sensex>
        <nifty>
            <CloseIndexValue>7818.60</CloseIndexValue>
            <trend>equal</trend>
            <premarket>false</premarket>
            <DateTime>03:53 PM | 10 Sep 2015</DateTime>
            <CurrentIndexValue>7788.10</CurrentIndexValue>
            <Segment>NSE</Segment>
            <OpenIndexValue>7729.05</OpenIndexValue>
            <IndexName>CNX NIFTY</IndexName>
            <PercentChange>-0.39</PercentChange>
            <NetChange>-30.50</NetChange>
        </nifty>
        <USD>
            <DateTime>2015-09-10 15:48:06.0</DateTime>
            <netChange>0.05</netChange>
            <percentChange>0.08</percentChange>
            <name>USD/INR</name>
            <bidprice>66.47</bidprice>
        </USD>
        <silver>
            <ClosePrice>35294.00</ClosePrice>
            <trend>negative</trend>
            <OpenPrice>35391.00</OpenPrice>
            <ExpiryDate>2015-12-04</ExpiryDate>
            <SpotSymbol>SSILVERAHM</SpotSymbol>
            <LastTradedPrice>35475.00</LastTradedPrice>
            <DateTime>10-September-2015 15:46:32</DateTime>
            <Symbol>SILVER</Symbol>
            <PercentChange>0.51</PercentChange>
            <CommodityName>Silver</CommodityName>
            <NetChange>181.00</NetChange>
            <SpotPrice>34912.0</SpotPrice>
            <PriceQuotationUnit>1 KGS  </PriceQuotationUnit>
        </silver>
        <marketstatus>
            <currentMarketStatus>Live</currentMarketStatus>
        </marketstatus>
        <gold>
            <ClosePrice>26057.00</ClosePrice>
            <trend>positive</trend>
            <OpenPrice>26143.00</OpenPrice>
            <ExpiryDate>2015-10-05</ExpiryDate>
            <SpotSymbol>SGOLDAHM</SpotSymbol>
            <LastTradedPrice>26067.00</LastTradedPrice>
            <DateTime>10-September-2015 15:46:15</DateTime>
            <Symbol>GOLD</Symbol>
            <PercentChange>0.04</PercentChange>
            <CommodityName>Gold</CommodityName>
            <NetChange>10.00</NetChange>
            <SpotPrice>26003.0</SpotPrice>
            <PriceQuotationUnit>10 GRMS </PriceQuotationUnit>
        </gold>
        <DXY Index>
            <DateTime>2015-09-10 15:49:21.0</DateTime>
            <netChange>0.1</netChange>
            <percentChange>0.1</percentChange>
            <name>DXY Index</name>
            <bidprice>96.11</bidprice>
        </DXY Index>
    </data>
</indexes>
```

but  this service is not call to  my xslt file why can u  please help me .

i check to this xml data validate in thsi  url http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0

than show to this error

```
Click on  to jump to the error. In the document, you can point at  with your mouse to see the error message. 
Errors in the XML document: 
    1:  1931    Attribute name "Index" associated with an element type "DXY" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

How to  resolve this error in front end .

Comment: Please, layout your code. One line of 2110 characters is utterly unreadable... and if you had done it, you may have spotted the obvious error immediately ;), see [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is because of this element in your XML

```
  <DXY Index>
     <DateTime>2015-09-10 15:49:21.0</DateTime>
     <netChange>0.1</netChange>
     <percentChange>0.1</percentChange>
     <name>DXY Index</name>
     <bidprice>96.11</bidprice>
  </DXY Index>
```

`DXY Index` is not a valid element name, as you can't have spaces in element names.

The XML needs to be corrected, so the name is something `DXYIndex` or `DXY-Index`, although the name you actually use will depend on what the XML is actually used for.